AppleScript - Find Recurring events within date range
I am trying to make a mirror of one calendar into another for the a set period of time (say 1 week). However when I run the script below it only copies non-recurring events. Any pointers on how to fix this is much appreciated
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later
use scripting additions

set SourceCalendarName to "VV Main"
set DestinationCalendarName to "VV Mirror"
set meetingProxy to "VV Meeting"
set today to current date

set numberofdays to 7
set startDay to ((current date) - (1 * days))
set time of startDay to 0
set endDay to ((startDay) + (numberofdays * days))
--set time of endDay to 

set numberOfEventsAdded to 0



tell application "Calendar"
    
    set sourceCalendar to calendar SourceCalendarName
    set destinationCalendar to calendar DestinationCalendarName
    
    (*
    tell destinationCalendar
        delete (events)
    end tell
    *)
    
    set sourceEventList to (events of sourceCalendar where (its start date > startDay) and (its start date < endDay))
    
    repeat with eventIdx from 1 to length of sourceEventList
        
        set newEvent to item eventIdx of sourceEventList
        
        --repeat with newEvent in (get events of sourceCalendar whose (start date is greater than startDay) and (start date is less than endDay))
        
        set existingEventList to (events of destinationCalendar)
        
        set eventExists to false
        
        if length of existingEventList is not 0 then
            repeat with checkEvent in existingEventList
                
                if ((start date of checkEvent = start date of newEvent) and (end date of checkEvent = end date of newEvent)) then
                    set eventExists to true
                    exit repeat
                end if
                
            end repeat
        end if
        
        if eventExists is false then
            tell destinationCalendar
                set destEvent to (make new event at end of events with properties {start date:start date of newEvent, end date:end date of newEvent, summary:meetingProxy, allday event:allday event of newEvent, description:(uid of newEvent as text)})
                if recurrence of destEvent is not missing value then
                    set recurrence of destEvent to recurrence of newEvent
                end if
                
            end tell
        end if
        
        --set numberOfEventsAdded to (numberOfEventsAdded + 1)
        
        
    end repeat
end tell


Looks like one needs to use CalendarLibEC from Shane (https://latenightsw.com/freeware/)
use script "CalendarLib EC" version "1.1.5"
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or later

use scripting additions


-- Change variables below
set SourceCalendarName to "VV Main"
set DestinationCalendarName to "VV Mirror"
set meetingProxy to "VV Meeting"
set addRecurringEvents to false
set numberofdays to 7

-- Changes should not be required below, but proceed at your own risk

set today to current date

set startDay to (today)
set time of startDay to 0
set endDay to (startDay + (numberofdays * days))

set numberOfEventsAdded to 0
set numberofEventsFailedtoCopy to 0

set theStore to («event !Cls!fst»)
-- The original script only compares events' start and end dates.
set destCal to («event !CLs!fca» DestinationCalendarName given «class !Cty»:«constant !Tct!TtC», «class !Cst»:theStore) -- change calendar type to suit
set existingEventList to («event !CLs!feS» given «class !Csd»:startDay, «class !Ced»:endDay, «class !Csc»:{destCal}, «class !Cst»:theStore)

repeat with thisEvent in existingEventList
    set {event_start_date:startDate, event_end_date:endDate} to («event !CLs!inf» given «class !Cev»:thisEvent)
    set thisEvent's contents to {startDate, endDate}
end repeat

set existingEventDates to existingEventList -- Use a different variable now for clarity.

-- Get the source calendar events which fall within the same date range.
set sourceCal to («event !CLs!fca» SourceCalendarName given «class !Cty»:«constant !Tct!TtC», «class !Cst»:theStore) -- change to suit
set sourceEventList to («event !CLs!feS» given «class !Csd»:startDay, «class !Ced»:endDay, «class !Csc»:{sourceCal}, «class !Cst»:theStore)
repeat with eventIdx from 1 to length of sourceEventList
    set newEvent to item eventIdx of sourceEventList
    -- Get the data of interest for each source event.\
    try
        set {event_external_ID:eventID, event_start_date:startDate, event_end_date:endDate, all_day:isAllday, event_is_recurring:isRecurring} to («event !CLs!inf» given «class !Cev»:newEvent)
        
        -- If its start and end dates aren't in existingEventDates, create a new event using the Calendar appplication..
        if (existingEventDates does not contain {{startDate, endDate}}) then
            
            tell application "Calendar"
                set destEvent to (make new event at end of calendar DestinationCalendarName's events with properties {start date:startDate, end date:endDate, summary:meetingProxy, allday event:isAllday})
                
                if addRecurringEvents is true then
                    if (isRecurring) then
                        set destEvent's recurrence to recurrence of event id eventID of calendar SourceCalendarName
                    end if
                end if
                
                set end of existingEventDates to {startDate, endDate} -- if required
                set numberOfEventsAdded to numberOfEventsAdded + 1
            end tell
            
        end if
        
    on error errMsg number -10000 --*** -L_NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:]: object cannot be nil (key: event_creation_date) 
        set eventIdx to {eventIdx + 1}
        set numberofEventsFailedtoCopy to (numberofEventsFailedtoCopy + 1)
        
    end try
    
end repeat

